# Clarifying the [sem] tag for simultaneous equation models?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [sem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sem) tag is described as being for structural equation modeling, but a proportion (my hunch: 25%) of its use is for (econometric) simultaneous equation models.

Is it worth clarifying, or splitting the tag?

Comment: On the basis that, sadly, nobody reads the documentation splitting it seems more likely to achieve anything.

Comment: Clarifying never hurts. You could also go through the threads & remove it from those not about SEM. (A few at a time, during slow periods, etc., as usual.)

Comment: @Gung - I've been doing that when the questions appear for a while. I feel a little bad that I don't have a tag to replace it with.

Comment: I think it's fine to just delete an inappropriate tag & replace it with nothing.

Comment: Although it may not be used this way at the moment, it's also worth noting that SEM is commonly used as an abbreviation for "standard error of the mean" (e.g. [Wikipedia does so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error)) which is another potential source of confusion for people adding a tag.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, **splitting** seems unnecessary since simultaneous equation models and structural equation models are essentially the same thing -- more precisely, simultaneous equation models are a special case of structural equation models (in the structural equation model world, so-called simultaneous equation models would be called path analysis models). This is according to, among others, [Bollen 1987](http://www.irss.unc.edu/content/pdf/Bollen%20(1987%20SM).pdf), who claims that this fact is well known. So anyway, to have two separate tags would seem to be splitting hairs, and I think it's actually rather convenient (for our purposes on this site) that they work out to have the same acronym and thus tag.

With that said, I suppose it couldn't hurt to **clarify** the `sem` tag description to point out that some people using this tag will only have the special case of simultaneous equation models in mind.